# Hornetq server is not starting from command line

Tags: hornetq

I downloaded HornetQ for a JMS 2.0 application and extracted on Windows. Inside HornetQ there is the `bin` folder. In the `bin` folder There are `.bat` files that can start and stop server and it works. If I opened a command prompt in the `bin` folder and run the command `hornetq start` it does not start the server. I tried on Google but I couldn’t find the specific command. Can you please help me to know the start and stop command for HornetQ server? I used ActiveMQ server and it successfully started on command prompt. I just wanted the same for the HornetQ.

Comment: Hi Justin, I download HornetQ for JMS2.0 application and extracted on windows, inside HornetQ there is bin folder. 1). There is .bat files that can start and stop server and it works.  2). If I opened command prompt on the same folder and using command “hornetq start” but it is not starting the server, I tried on google but I couldn’t find its specific command. Can you please help me to know the start and stop command for hornetq server. I used Activemq server and it successfully started on command prompt, I just wanted the same for the hornetq.

Answer (score 0):

The commands to start and stop HornetQ from the command prompt are `run` and `stop` which correspond to the `run.bat` and `stop.bat` batch files in the `bin` directory. The reason you can start ActiveMQ 5.x with `activemq start` is because ActiveMQ 5.x ships a batch file named `activemq.bat` in its `bin` directory. You can't really expect to use the same command format with different brokers because they are, in fact, *different* and support different methods for starting and stopping.

That said, I'm curious why you're using HornetQ at all at this point. The HornetQ code-based was donated to the Apache ActiveMQ project over 5 years ago now and exists as the [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) broker. Why don't you use that so you can have a broker under active development? Hundreds of bugs have been fixed and a ton of new features have been added in the previous 5 years.

Comment: Thanks Justin for explanation, since I am a learner and I believe in order to get exposure on a topic I go to it's root by API doc because where we can get exact knowledge about what causes its origin, how many versions how many updates involved. I have done POC on Classic JMS API to Spring JMS(1.1,2.x) integration and going on Kafka now a days, during 1.1 I did it but for HornetQ it was not appear the commands on CMD by external resources so I came to this platform and I get here good response.

Comment: I used 'start' command on /bin folder's CMD then it opened an new CMD tab. If I use 'run' command then it starts the server and for I stop I used ctrl+c then 'Y' and it worked.

Comment: Yes, it should be `run` not `start` since the batch file is `run.bat`. That was a typo on my part. I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: BTW, I still don't understand why you're using HornetQ.

Comment: Please read my comment carefully you will understand, if you have any problem in understanding my comment then please let me know. I have find out my solution and I will close this thread soon.

Comment: I've read your comment many times, and I still don't understand why you're using HornetQ.

Comment: I am developing JMS proof of concepts from its beginning version to latest Message Brokers with frameworks..this my way of learning.

Comment: OK, but JMS is the specification of an *API* not a broker. In my opinion using an old broker that is no longer under active development isn't a good way to learn how to use JMS. Any proof-of-concept created with such a broker will not be practical to implement in production.

Answer (score 0):

[Running HornetQ from CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjAg0.png)

Here Start command is 'run' and for stopping the server we may use Ctrl+c command and then press 'Y'